# MySQL is not showing any error messages

Tags: mysql, sql

When I execute sql statements with errors, mySQL is not telling me if I have an syntax error or any other kind of error, neither shows me if the statement was executed sucessfully.

I trying to execute statements without the wizard's workbench, I mean, I writing directly the statements.

For example, if I execute this:

```
insert into PROFF(aVARCHAR) values ('aVARCHAR')
```

it shows nothing.

If i execute the correct query without the single quotes mistake:

```
insert into PROFF(aVARCHAR) values (`aVARCHAR`)
```

it shows nothing neither.

Is there something I need to set up in order to see the error messages?

Comment: Your second example is not correct; backticks are for identifiers. Other than that: are you seeing data being inserted into the `PROFF` table?  If not, you might need to commit the transaction. Best of luck.

Comment: What tool are you using to enter the statements?  What environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Workbench 5.2.38 for Ubuntu 11.10 64 bits

Comment: @bernie Ok, but that's the problem. It should shows me that syntax error, but it's not doing it.

Comment: Are you executing from WB? Might be another bug in that :P Did you try another tool or MySQL command line?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The bottom panel was hidden. That's why I couldn't see any error messages.

Comment: If all else fails, deleting the options file is one way of fixing this (~/.mysql/workbench/wb_options.xml on Linux)

Comment: To show it: just slide the bar at the bottom: it is still here but with a height of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick sanity check, you are typing a semi-colon (";") after you enter the statement, right? It won't run a statement given via the mysql command-line client until you do.

Comment: Well, that's the problem it should show an error message telling me that I miss a semicolon...

Comment: It won't because it doesn't know you are done typing until it sees the semi colon. It is perfectly valid to have an SQL statement that spans multiple lines.

Comment: I tried putting the semicolon (the right way), but yet I'm not getting error messages