# MySQL no longer shows error message, only code

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Since I upgraded to MYSQL 5.7.16, I no longer have error messages, which is annoying (I now have to remember all codes) and gets very very annoying when it comes to `SQL 1064` (`Error: 1064 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_PARSE_ERROR) %s near '%s' at line %d` [says the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html)... so easy to debug with no info nor line number).

Same goes for warnings: if a line returns a warning, I can no longer read it (`show warnings` doesn't crash, but it returns no result).

So I bet (hope!) MySQL made a configuration change: **what's the option to get the MySQL error messages back?**

Comment: are you trying it from PHPMyAdmin or command prompt?

Comment: See this post once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899427/mysql-is-not-showing-any-error-messages

Comment: @Rahul I use HeidiSQL (not PHPMyAdmin), but I have the same issue on a command prompt: a mysql 5.7.16 `use nothing;` returns `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown error 1049` while 5.7.10 returned `Error 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'nothing'`

Comment: @Rahul It's not a hidden pannel since it occurs on CLI too (and since HeidiSQL & CLI shows that an error occued, but show an empty message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the lc-messages-dir directive. 
In last versions, the default dir is wrong (at least under Debian).

Put this into your mysql.cnf :

```
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql/english/
```

And error messages will be back ;)

Comment: That makes sense! I actually no longer have this issue (and I even did not notice it "fixed itself") since I've moved my dev environment from XAMPP to WAMP (prod is fine, hosting service probably fixed this config line by themselves). I'll mark it as accepted then, even if I'm unsure it was the solution (but it seems so)